# Grouping/Clustering results based on shared values

Tags: clustering

I have a data set that is similar to this:

- 10,000 jobs with 200,000 applicants which are linked to a job.

I'm looking to cluster the shared jobs based on applicants that they share, am I reinventing the wheel looking to build this or is there a common solution?

Most of the example I found all require a "distance" but I can't see how I could compute one in this case?

**Edit:** To add, the clustering criteria would be fairly straightforward more than X applicants (say 5) in common, with only a single cluster per job.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on the criteria to cluster the jobs?  In general, a question is expected to articulate enough detail so that an adequate answer could be identified or upvoted.

Comment: Thanks @Apass.Jack I've added some more context - essentially I want to group where the job applicants intersect by more than 5 across jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [the Jaccard distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) to compare two jobs: i.e., the distance between two jobs is

$$d(A,B) = {|A \cap B| \over |A \cup B|},$$

where $A$ is the set of applicants for the first job and $B$ is the set of applicants for the second job.  Then, use any standard clustering algorithm with this distance measure.

Comment: Thanks, so I'd execute that against all jobs and build a matrix from that then is then fed into a clustering algorithm?

Comment: @williamvicary, yes (all pairs of jobs, not all jobs).